# WooCommerce-WorldPay checkout taking forever to complete

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, worldpay

I've been having trouble getting the Online Worldpay plugin (from https://wordpress.paymentplugins.com/product-category/worldpay/) to work with WooCommerce and after multiple trial and error, although it seems to be working now, it's taking forever to complete a transaction.

The first issue was this in the server log:

```
upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream
```

After searching on SO and a few trial and error, adding the following nginx directives seem to have fixed it:

```
proxy_connect_timeout 159s;
proxy_send_timeout   600;
proxy_read_timeout   600;
```

However it's still not fixed the problem. It's taking up to 5 minutes between clicking checkout and showing the confirmation page.

Here's my server log:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [29/Aug/2018:11:51:40 +0100] "POST /staging/wp- 
admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.0" 200 1140 "https://website.com/staging/wp-        admin/edit.php?post_type=shop_order" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)     AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [29/Aug/2018:11:49:02 +0100] "POST /staging/?wc-    ajax=checkout HTTP/1.0" 200 1522 "https://website.com/staging/checkout/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [29/Aug/2018:11:53:17 +0100] "GET /staging/checkout/order-received/1001?key=wc_order_5b867a1e36616 HTTP/1.0" 301 4616 "https://website.com/staging/checkout/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [29/Aug/2018:11:53:17 +0100] "GET /staging/checkout/order-received/1001/?key=wc_order_5b867a1e36616 HTTP/1.0" 200 77776 "https://website.com/staging/checkout/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [29/Aug/2018:11:53:18 +0100] "GET /staging/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/fromUpload/37124872560_f78336501a_k-3-1024x485.jpg HTTP/1.0" 200 491 "-" "-"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [29/Aug/2018:11:53:18 +0100] "GET /staging/wp-content/themes/website/functions/includes/im_cart_order.php?path=https://website.com/staging/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/fromUpload/37124872560_f78336501a_k-3-1024x485.jpg&crop_left=26.329113924050635&crop_top=0&crop_width=47.34177215189874&crop_height=100&rotate=0&filter=0&mirror=0&flip=0 HTTP/1.0" 200 59870 "https://website.com/staging/checkout/order-received/1001/?key=wc_order_5b867a1e36616" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36"
```

Appreciate any insight :)

Thanks!

Comment: For anyone coming across this issue, our issue was WP MAIL SMTP Plugin. Deactivating it fixed the issue.